# Need explanation why below elasticsearch query giving different result based on custom settings and mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created index called "my_index". It will have field "my_text". (elasticsearch 7.5.1)

While creating index, I am giving these type of settings and mappings.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.max_ngram_diff": "8",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "11",
          "token_chars": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that I have inserted docs as per below:  GET my_index/_search

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "CustomString"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "Quick brown foxes leap over lazy dogs in summer"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I am trying these 2 search queries:

1)

```
GET my_index/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_text": "brown fox"
    }
  }
}

Output:

{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 12.057516,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 12.057516,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 11.515859,
        "_source" : {
          "my_text" : "Quick brown foxes leap over lazy dogs in summer"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2)

```
GET my_index/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "my_text": "brown fox"
    }
  }
}

Output:

{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

**I have checked `match` and `phrase match` documentation and after executing above search queries, I got confused about understanding.**

**Can anyone explain what is happening behind the scene and what I am missing/misunderstood?**

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** this happening because of analyzer in mapping with n-gram tokenizer.

**Long answer:** You using tokenizer based on `n-gram`, and n-gram as followed from documentation:

> The ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.
>
> N-grams are like a sliding window that moves across the word - a continuous sequence of characters of the specified length. They are useful for querying languages that don’t use spaces or that have long compound words, like German.

So it dividing your text into words, and at this time `mach_phrase` trying to set phrase from this words. Problem that based on your settings, you will have not simple words, but parts of sentence in window. You can check this using  [testing analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/_testing_analyzers.html) tool.

**Example based on your analyzer**:

```
GET my_index/_analyze 
{
  "field": "my_text", 
  "text":  "Quick brown fox leap over lazy dogs in summer"
}

Part of answer (whole answer is too big to paste here - you can try in Kibana)
{
  "token" : "k brown fo",
  "start_offset" : 4,
  "end_offset" : 14,
  "type" : "word",
  "position" : 43
},
{
  "token" : "k brown fox",
  "start_offset" : 4,
  "end_offset" : 15,
  "type" : "word",
  "position" : 44
},
```

As you see from example -  your text divided to chunks with type word.

To check how it will work without and with, you can create little experiment. Remove your analyzer from field in mapping (so field will be mapped as standard), and pass analyzer option to `match_phrase` query. Also you can add `"explain": true` to query to see what happening in details on match.
Example:

```
Mapping without analyzer: 
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.max_ngram_diff": "8",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "11",
          "token_chars": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_text": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

Queries with and without analyzer:
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "my_text": {
        "query": "brown fox",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "my_text": {
        "query": "brown fox",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

You will see the difference.